# Shared Memory's atomicAdd with int and float have different SASS

Tags: sass, cuda, atomic, gpu-shared-memory

I encountered a performance issue, where the shared memory's `atomicAdd` on `float` is much more expensive than it on `int` after profiling with `nv-nsight-cu-cli`.
After checking the generated SASS, I found the generated SASS of the shared memory's `atomicAdd` on `float` and `int` are not similar at all.

Here I show a example in minimal cuda code:

```sh
$ cat test.cu                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
__global__ void testAtomicInt() {
    __shared__ int SM_INT;
    SM_INT = 0;
    __syncthreads();
    atomicAdd(&(SM_INT), ((int)1));
}

__global__ void testAtomicFloat() {
    __shared__ float SM_FLOAT;
    SM_FLOAT = 0.0;
    __syncthreads();
    atomicAdd(&(SM_FLOAT), ((float)1.1));
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_86 -c test.cu 
$ cuobjdump -sass test.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_86
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

    code for sm_86
        Function : _Z15testAtomicFloatv
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM86 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM86)"
        /*0000*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x28] ;                  /* 0x00000a0000017a02 */
                                                                           /* 0x000fc40000000f00 */
        /*0010*/                   STS [RZ], RZ ;                          /* 0x000000ffff007388 */
                                                                           /* 0x000fe80000000800 */
        /*0020*/                   BAR.SYNC 0x0 ;                          /* 0x0000000000007b1d */
                                                                           /* 0x000fec0000000000 */
        /*0030*/                   LDS R2, [RZ] ;                          /* 0x00000000ff027984 */
                                                                           /* 0x000e240000000800 */
        /*0040*/                   FADD R3, R2, 1.1000000238418579102 ;    /* 0x3f8ccccd02037421 */
                                                                           /* 0x001fcc0000000000 */
        /*0050*/                   ATOMS.CAST.SPIN R3, [RZ], R2, R3 ;      /* 0x00000002ff03738d */
                                                                           /* 0x000e240001800003 */
        /*0060*/                   ISETP.EQ.U32.AND P0, PT, R3, 0x1, PT ;  /* 0x000000010300780c */
                                                                           /* 0x001fda0003f02070 */
        /*0070*/              @!P0 BRA 0x30 ;                              /* 0xffffffb000008947 */
                                                                           /* 0x000fea000383ffff */
        /*0080*/                   EXIT ;                                  /* 0x000000000000794d */
                                                                           /* 0x000fea0003800000 */
        /*0090*/                   BRA 0x90;                               /* 0xfffffff000007947 */
                                                                           /* 0x000fc0000383ffff */
        /*00a0*/                   NOP;                                    /* 0x0000000000007918 */
        ..........


        Function : _Z13testAtomicIntv
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM86 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM86)"
        /*0000*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x28] ;         /* 0x00000a0000017a02 */
                                                                  /* 0x000fc40000000f00 */
        /*0010*/                   STS [RZ], RZ ;                 /* 0x000000ffff007388 */
                                                                  /* 0x000fe80000000800 */
        /*0020*/                   BAR.SYNC 0x0 ;                 /* 0x0000000000007b1d */
                                                                  /* 0x000fec0000000000 */
        /*0030*/                   ATOMS.POPC.INC.32 RZ, [URZ] ;  /* 0x00000000ffff7f8c */
                                                                  /* 0x000fe2000d00003f */
        /*0040*/                   EXIT ;                         /* 0x000000000000794d */
                                                                  /* 0x000fea0003800000 */
        /*0050*/                   BRA 0x50;                      /* 0xfffffff000007947 */
                                                                  /* 0x000fc0000383ffff */
        /*0060*/                   NOP;                           /* 0x0000000000007918 */
        ..........



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_86
code version = [7,5]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
```

From the generated SASS code above, we could clearly obtain, that the shared memory's `atomicAdd` on `int` generates single lightweight `ATOMS.POPC.INC.32 RZ, [URZ]`, while it on `float` generating a bunch of SASS with a heavyweight `ATOMS.CAST.SPIN R3, [RZ], R2, R3` .

The [CUDA Binary Utilities](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html) doesn't show me the meaning of `CAST` or `SPIN`. However, I could guess it means an exclusive spin lock on a shared memory address. (Correct me, if my guess goes wrong.)
In my real code, none of the SASS of `atomicAdd` of `int` has a hotspot. However, this `ATOMS.CAST.SPIN` is significantly hotter than other SASS code generated by of the `atomicAdd` of `float`.

In addition, I tested with compiler flag `-arch=sm_86`, `-arch=sm_80` and `-arch=sm_75`. Under those CCs, the generated SPSS code of `atomicAdd` of `float` is very similar. Another fact is, with no surprise, the `atomicAdd` of `double` generates SPSS alike it of `float`.

---

This observation caused me more confusion than questions. I would go with some simple questions from my profiling experience and hope we could have a nice discussion.

- What does exactly `ATOMS.CAST.SPIN` do? The only SASS document I am aware of is the [CUDA Binary Utilities](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html).
- Why should the `atomicAdd` of `float` generates more SASS code and does more work than it on `int`? I know it is a general question and hard to be answered. Maybe the `ATOMS.POPC.INC` simply doesn't apply to data type `float` or `double`?
- If it is more vulnerable to have **more shared memory load and store conflict** and thus **more stall time** for the `atomicAdd` of `float` than the `atomicAdd` of `int`? The former has clearly more instruction to be executed and divergent branches. I have the following code snippet in my project where the number of function calls on two functions is the same. However, the `atomicAdd` of `float` builds a runtime bottleneck while it is on `int` doesn't.

```
atomicAdd(&(SM_INT), ((int)1));  // no hotspot
atomicAdd(&(SM_FLOAT), ((float)1.1)); // a hotspot
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the target hardware you are compiling for lacks hardware floating point atomic add instructions and thus has to use a non-atomic add with a test and set loop to ensure the result is correctly inserted into shared memory

Comment: @talonmies Is that fix-able with a modern GPU to include the floating-point atomic add instructions, which is missing at mine?

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella. Thanks! I agree with you and would delete my linked comment. Do you think your comment is more helpful if it were added to your answer?

Comment: On Ampere `atomicAdd(&MySharedData,1) is a specially optimized. See: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/on-demand/session/gtcspring21-s33322/  (Yes, this is hidden behind a registration wall, but reg. is free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably won't be able to provide an answer addressing every possible question.  CUDA SASS is really not documented to the level to explain these things.

> What does exactly ATOMS.CAST.SPIN do? The only SASS document I am aware of is the CUDA Binary Utilities.

```
ATOMS.CAST.SPIN
^^^^^ ^^^     
   ||   |  
   ||   compare and swap
   |shared
   atomic
```

The [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) gives an indication of how one can implement an "arbitrary" atomic operation, using atomic CAS (Compare And Swap).  You should first familiarize yourself with how atomic CAS [works](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas).

Regarding the "arbitrary atomic" example, the thing to note is that it can evidently be used to provide atomic operations for e.g. datatypes that are not supported by a "native" atomic instruction, such as atomic add.  Another thing to note is that it is essentially a loop around an atomic CAS instruction, with the loop checking to see if the operation was "successful" or not.  If it was "unsuccessful", the loop continues.  If it was "successful", the loop exits.

This is effectively what we see depicted in SASS code in your `float` example:

```
/*0030*/  LDS R2, [RZ] ;  // get the current value in the location
FADD R3, R2, 1.1000000238418579102 ; // perform ordinary floating-point add
ATOMS.CAST.SPIN R3, [RZ], R2, R3 ;  //  attempt to atomically replace the result in the location
ISETP.EQ.U32.AND P0, PT, R3, 0x1, PT ; // check if replacement was successful
@!P0 BRA 0x30   // if not, loop and try again
```

These are essentially the steps that are outlined in the "arbitrary atomic" example in the programming guide.  Based on this I would conclude the following:

- the architecture you compiled for does not actually have a "native" atomic operation of the type you are requesting
- the atomic operation you are requesting can be done using the looping method
- the compiler tool chain (typically `ptxas`, but could also be the JIT system), as a convenience feature, is automatically implementing this looping method for you, rather than throwing a compile error

> Why should the atomicAdd of float generates more SASS code and does more work than it on int?

Evidently, the architecture you are compiling for does not have a "native" implementation of atomic add for `float`, and so the compiler tool chain has chosen to implement this looping method for you.  Since the loop effectively involves the possibility of success/failure which will determine whether this loop continues, and success/failure depends on other threads behavior (contention to perform the atomic), the looping method may do considerably more "work" than a native single instruction will.

> If it is more vulnerable to have more shared memory load and store conflict and thus more stall time for the atomicAdd of float than the atomicAdd of int?

Yes, I personally would conclude that the native atomic method is more efficient, and the looping method may be less efficient, which could be expressed in a variety of ways in the profiler, such as warp stalls.

EDIT:

1. It's possible for things to be implemented/available in one GPU architecture but not another.  This is certainly applicable to atomics, and you can see examples of this if you read the previously linked section on atomics in the programming guide.  I don't know of any architectures today that are "newer" than cc8.0 or cc8.6 (Ampere) but it is certainly possible that the behavior of a future (or any other) GPU could be different here.
2. This loop-around-atomicCAS method is distinct from a previous methodology ([lock/update/unlock](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/maxwell-tuning-guide/index.html#fast-shared-memory-atomics), which also involves a loop for lock negotiation) the compiler toolchain used on [Kepler and prior architectures](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-fast-histograms-using-shared-atomics-maxwell/) to provide atomics on shared memory when no formal SASS instructions existed to do so.

Comment: It is the assembler rather than the compiler which is doing the lowering of the atomic add to the set and test loop design pattern in this case. The compiler is emitting `atom.shared.add.f32` or `atom.shared.add.u32` in the two cases.

Comment: Yes, the ptxas tool is doing this.  I was referring to the entire toolchain process as "the compiler".

Comment: I commented, because one could conceivably hand write PTX and load it straight onto the GPU via the driver API in the misguided belief that avoiding the nasty compiler would "fix" this, and the JIT assembler will just do the same thing anyway...

Answer (score 2):

The `atomicInc(&MySharedInt)` (aka `atomicAd(&MySharedInt, 1)` instruction has been re-engineered in hardware to perform the following function.

(Pseudo code of the hardware implementation)

```
__device__ int WarpAtomicIncrement(int* sharedData) {
    const auto old = *sharedData;
    const auto addition = __popc(__activemask());
    const auto result = old + addition;
    if (LaneId() == 0) { sharedData[0] = result; }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, there is no longer contention, between threads updating the same shared memory address, as long as the increment is 1.

Source: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/on-demand/session/gtcspring21-s33322/
At around 8:33.

[image]

Obviously NVidia could have done the same optimization for consistent additions > 1 and for floating point additions, but they decided to allocate their transistor budget elsewhere.